# Rendering in React from JSON

Tags: json, reactjs, redux, react-router

I have a little bug in my app and can't fix it.
I need to render images from JSON.
First of all, I have a number of albums:

**AlbumLayout**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router';


class AlbumLayout extends Component {
        handleClick(album){
            browserHistory.push({
                pathname: "album/" + album.id,
                state: {albumDetails: album}
            });
    }

    renderList(){

        return this.props.albums.map((album) => {
            return(

                <li onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, album)} key={album.id}>                 
                        <img alt="job" src={album.img} />
                        <p className="album_titulo">{album.title}</p>
                </li>

            );
        });
    }


    render(){

        return (

            <div>
                <div className="albums">
                    <div className="albums_caixa">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-xs-12">
                                <ul className="no_pad">
                                    {this.renderList()}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}


function mapStateToProps(state){

    return {

        albums: state.album

    };
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AlbumLayout);
```

Every albums has own list of images:

**List of images**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class AlbumsShow extends Component {


    renderImage(mainData, imageIdx){
        let jobDetails = this.props.albums.filter( t => t.id == this.props.params.id)[0];
        return (
                <div key={imageIdx} className='content'>
                  {mainData.images.map((image, etag) => {
                  return(
                      <div key={image.etag} className='content_box'>
                        <img key={image.etag} src={image.images.smallThumbnail} alt="book"/>
                      </div>
                      )
                  })}
                </div>
            )
    }


    render(){
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.image.map(this.renderImage)}
      </div>
    );
  }

}

function mapStateToProps({image}) {
  return {image};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AlbumsShow);
```

When user click on any Album, he should see list of images, which is parsing from JSON.

```
{
    "images": {
        "id": "01",
        "etag": "01",
        "images": {
          "kind": "image",
          "id": "1",
          "etag": "1",
          "smallThumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=FaaQgVCaXU4C&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"
        }
      }
  }
```

As for me, I have mistake in **List of images**-file, but I can't find it.
I will really appreciate for any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm where are you using the `jobDetails` in your `#renderImage`

Comment: also you could try using `.find` rather than `.filter(x => x.id = params.id)[0]`
[Docs Available Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=example)

Comment: @RobWilkinson, actually I think jobDetails in not need here. I wrote it, because I tried to add images from reducers, this is works, but then I decided to put all images to JSON:

`render(){
let jobDetails = this.props.trabalhos.filter( t => t.id == this.props.params.id)[0];
return (
<div>
<img src={jobDetails.img} />
</div> 
);
}`

Comment: Are you trying to map over objects? or are both images values actually arrays of objects?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may just need to bind the `this` context in your `.map` function:

```
return (
  <div>
    {this.props.image.map(this.renderImage.bind(this))}
  </div>
);
```

It also looks like you might need to add `albums` to your connect in that component.

Comment: idk if it makes a difference - but you can bind to the this in the constructor too.